# Code for Pro Javascript won't running

Tags: javascript, html

I don't think won't is the right word here.  I *can't* make it run.

It's a very simple piece of code.  If I just type in `alert("Working");` it runs fine.

In any case, here is the entire code and maybe you guys can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    })

</script>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Press me">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you running this on? `attachEvent` won't work on most modern browsers.

Comment: Oh, also I'm using Firefox 24.0. That doesn't sound right, but it is what About Firefox, said... are we really all the way to 24.0?  Wow, I haven't been paying attention.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in here

Comment: Yeh apparently it doesn't work.  And neither does addEventListener?  Correct me if I'm wrong, because I tried that before this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple issues:

1. Your code can't run until AFTER the document is loaded.  It won't find the objects in the page yet if it runs too soon.  The easiest way to do this is to just move the code block to right before the `</body>` tag.
2. `attachEvent()` is only for old versions of IE.  All modern browsers support `.addEventListener()`.

Revised HTML/code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Events</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Press me">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Dmqdn/

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks.  This was right.  I just don't have the rep to upvote.

Comment: @JerryWalker - After the right amount of time has passed, you can still pick one of the answers as your "best answer" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work on FF (and other modern browsers):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Clicked');
    });
});
```

It's safest to ensure the DOM is loaded fully before trying to access it.

I've used `console.log`, you should become familiar with it, it will help you out a lot. Check out FireBug for FF, the dev tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4k7C/) illustrating the solution. You need to do two things to make this work:

1. Move the `<script>` tag below the input
2. Replace `attachEvent` with `addEventListener`. `attachEvent` is [no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here's the code:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Press me">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    })
</script>
```